# Ubuntu xBindKeys not working for mouse buttons

Tags: ubuntu, xbindkeys

I've configured back and forward button a while ago with xBindKeys and I am sure that everything was fine. Yesterday I've noticed that those two functionalities somehow swapped. Back button functions as forward and forward as back.

I've check my configuration once again and everything seems to be fine. Also, when I swap button indexes just to check whether it works, nothing happens.

Ubuntu 18.04

```
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'keydown Right' 'keyup Right' 'keyup Alt_L'"
b:8

"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'keydown Left' 'keyup Left' 'keyup Alt_L'"
b:9
```